# Android - saved image file doesn't load after onResume

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-camera-intent

A feature in my app is taking a picture through the camera app, saving it in external storage and then placing it in an ImageView in the activity that called the camera. The code looks like this:

```
public class ProjectActivity extends Activity {

private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpeg";
private Bitmap _ImageBitmap;
private ImageView _ImageView;
private int _index;
private String _CurrentPhotoPath;
```

The onCreate method finds the ImageView and sets it if the bitmap member has been initiated (for a feature I want to add later):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project);

    if(_ImageBitmap != null)
        _ImageView.setImageBitmap(_ImageBitmap);
}
```

The onResume method should load the image to the ImageView if the bitmap has been initialized:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(_ImageBitmap != null)
        _ImageView.setImageBitmap(_ImageBitmap);
    super.onResume();
}
```

The methods for taking the picture, they all work fine up to the point of resuming the activity:

```
public void takePicture(View view){
    this.dispatchTakePictureIntent(0);
}

/**
 * invokes an intent to take a picture
 * @param actionCode
 */
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
    String action = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE;
    if(Data.isIntentAvailable(this, action)){
            if(this.isExternalStorageWritable()){
            File f = createImageFile();
            if(f != null){
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(action);

                //takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 *  Checks if external storage is available for read and write 
 */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private File createImageFile() {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = this._projName + getIndex();
    File image;
    File dir = getAlbumDir(this, this.getAlbumName());
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, 
            JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
            dir
        );
        _CurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}

private File getAlbumDir(Context context, String albumName) {
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    file.mkdirs();
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        return null;
    }
    return file;
}

private String getAlbumName() {
    return this._projName;
}

private String getIndex() {
    this._index++;
    return String.valueOf(this._index);
}
```

Upon returning from the Image Capture Action, the onActivityResult returns with resultCode -1 and the data from the camera app:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch(requestCode){
        case 0:
            if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
            }
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

In this method I'm extracting the bitmap from the intent and load it into the ImageView

```
/**
 * adds the picture unto an ImageView
 * @param intent
 */
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    _ImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    _ImageView.setImageBitmap(_ImageBitmap);
}
```

}

This is the layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ProjectActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/project_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/project_image_view" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_picture_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_picture_button_text"
        android:onClick="takePicture" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/make_movie_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/make_movie_button_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have camera and external storage permissions.

When I test this, I can see the picture just fine after I take it and return to this activity, but once onResume is called (due to monitor rotation of the camera app), the image disappears and I can only see the buttons.

Help would be appreciated, Idan

update: for some reason _ImageBitmap is null the second time onResume is called. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: I think your activity is destroyed during rotation, therefore your _ImageBitmap is recreated as null.  You need to somehow save the bitmap data in a bundle and save it during  onSaveInstanceState , and get the bundle during oncreate or onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: I've succesfully managed to save the _currentFilePath into shared preferences, and I manage to load it succesfully in onResume, but the image view still won't load:
1. Trying to read _ImageBitmap from file using BitmapFactory.decodeFile() - no bitmap created.
2. Trying to set the _ImageView using SetImageUri - the Uri is created correctly, but the imageview isn't updated.

Comment: PS, trying to compress the bitmap then using BitmapFactory to decode using _CurrentFilePath returns null as well

Comment: maybe try to hard code the path to your image (instead of downloading) just to test if the logic is correct?

Comment: After re-reading the SharedPreferences documentation I found out it's persistent across user sessions, so my file path never changed... I tried using SavedInstanceState to save the file path and that works, as long as you don't quit the app. To save the image across sessions I used the shared preferences, and only if the bundle was null. And that solved my issues. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, maybe you can write your solution and mark that as the correct answer to help others who might run into the same issue.